# Mocking function argument names to work with inspect.getargspec

Tags: python, python-2.7, inspect, python-mock

I'm trying to mock a function for a test that eventually passes the mock through the `inspect.getargspec` function. I'd like to use some specific names as argument names of the mocked function.

As far as I know, there's no specific way to mock argument names, so I'm trying to use Mock's `spec=` argument:

```
In [1]: import mock, inspect

In [2]: inspect.getargspec(mock.Mock(spec=lambda a,b:None))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-de358c5a968d> in <module>()
----> 1 inspect.getargspec(mock.Mock(spec=lambda a,b:None))

/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.pyc in getargspec(func)
    815     if not isfunction(func):
    816         raise TypeError('{!r} is not a Python function'.format(func))
--> 817     args, varargs, varkw = getargs(func.func_code)
    818     return ArgSpec(args, varargs, varkw, func.func_defaults)
    819 

/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.pyc in getargs(co)
    750 
    751     if not iscode(co):
--> 752         raise TypeError('{!r} is not a code object'.format(co))
    753 
    754     nargs = co.co_argcount

TypeError: <Mock name='mock.func_code' id='140395908951120'> is not a code object
```

So, yes, indeed, Mock is not a code object. How do I mock argument names so that `inspect.getargspec` returns these names?

Comment: One point of a `Mock` object is that it is often easier to create than writing a proper mock class or mock function.  If the `Mock` class doesn't simplify things for you, simply write a mock function instead.  (I know you won't get the function call tracking functionality for free, but maybe you don't even need it.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Yeah, actually I wanted to use Mock because of call tracking. But maybe you're right…

Comment: You could call a mock from within your mock function for tracking. :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach: could you put both of these into an answer, so that I can properly upvote you?

Comment: I've elaborated the comments in a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to find a workaround that almost doesn't hurt. So, following the example from the question text:

```
In [1]: import mock, inspect
```

Define the spec function (assigned to an identifier because I'll need it twice later):

```
In [2]: specfun = lambda a,b: None
```

Define the mock. After doing some experiments I noticed that `inspect.getargspec` simply needs a `func_code` object:

```
In [3]: mockfun = mock.Mock(spec=specfun, func_code=specfun.func_code)
```

Does it work with `inspect.getargspec`? Yes!

```
In [4]: inspect.getargspec(mockfun)
Out[4]: ArgSpec(args=['a', 'b'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=<Mock name='mock.func_defaults' id='140160757665168'>)
```

Does it work like a normal callable Mock? Yes!

```
In [5]: mockfun('hello', 42)
Out[5]: <Mock name='mock()' id='140160757483984'>

In [6]: mockfun.call_args_list
Out[6]: [call('hello', 42)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could patch `inspect.getargspec` instead:

```
getargspec_orig = inspect.getargspec
def getargspec_patch(f):
    if f == <your function>:
        return ArgSpec(args=[...], varargs=..., keywords=..., defaults=(...))
    else:
        return getargspec_orig(f)

with patch('inspect.getargspec', new_callable=getargspec_patch):
    # do your testing here
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to use a proper mock function instead of a `mock.Mock` instance.  If you need the call tracking of `Mock` instances and the implicit creation of `Mock` instances as return values, you can simply call such an instance from within your mock function:

```
def test_something(self):
    mock_instance = mock.Mock()
    def mock_callback(a, b):
        return mock_instance(a, b)
    result = function_to_test(mock_callback)
    self.assertEqual(mock_instance.call_count, 3)
```

If you need the callback in several functions (or don't want it to be a local function for a different reason), you can write a factory function that returns both the callback and the `Mock` instance:

```
def make_mock_callback():
    mock_instance = mock.Mock()
    def mock_callback(a, b):
        return mock_instance(a, b)
    return mock_instance, mock_callback
```

By closing over `mock_instance`, you make sure each callback gets its own `Mock` without polluting the prototype of the function.